# CRM 2013 SP1 On-Prem: Mailbox stuck in: "The email configuration test is in progress" status

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a main incoming mailbox in CRM (sort of like a contact@organisation.com address) but for some reason today, the mail has stopped flowing into CRM.

I have tried resetting the async services as mentioned here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/159892

But the mailbox remains stuck.

I have also tried enabling tracing on the backend servers but even have 20 minutes I didn't find any issues in the trace logs...

***EDIT***

So the process completed at 4am this morning and I can't work out why the test took over 17 hours to complete without error.

What is odd is all the async jobs ran yesterday (in a timely matter) without issue and I did not find any errors related to this email issue in the trace logs.

I am concerned with why this process took so long without any indication of an issue and I would be happy for someone to raise some suggestions

Comment: Do you have any errors on the email server side?

Comment: Nope, the async server is being used as the email server but I didn't see a single error or warning regarding the emails

Comment: This is one of the bigger downsides with server side sync, you have really NO idea what the heck is happening. I share your pain.